# Convert float[] to byte[] for NAudio

Tags: c#, naudio

I am receiving a string representing an array of audio samples from a browser captured via getUserMedia.  getUserMedia is recording at 48000, and I am interleaving 2 channels before I send the string values to the server.  I turn this string into a float[] like so:

```
string[] raw = buffer.ToString().Split(new char[]{ ',' });
float[] fArray = new float[raw.Length];
for (int x = 0; x < raw.Length; x++)
{
     float sampleVal = float.Parse(raw[x]);
     fArray[x] = sampleVal;
}
```

What I would like to do is convert the float[] array into a byte[] array so that I can pass it to a BufferedWaveProvider (48000, 16, 1) for playback.  Here's how I am currently trying to do the conversion:

```
byte[] bSamples = new byte[fArray.Length * 2];
for (int x = 0; x < fArray.Length; x += 2)
{
    short sSample = (short)Math.Floor(fArray[x] * 32767);

    byte[] tmp = BitConverter.GetBytes(sSample);
    bSamples[x] = tmp[0];
    bSamples[x + 1] = tmp[1];
}
```

Using the code above, only is garbage produced.  Can anyone point me in the right direction for doing such a conversion?

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689410/convert-32-bit-float-audio-to-16-bit-byte-array?rq=1), but it didn't get me where I need to go.

Comment: I've made a little progress on this.  The conversion loop should look more like this:
    int destOffset = 0;
    byte[] destArray = new byte[fArray.Length * 2];
    for (int x = 0; x < fArray.Length; x++)
    {
         float sample32 = fArray[x];

        byte[] tmp = BitConverter.GetBytes((short)(sample32 * 32768f));

        destArray[destOffset] = tmp[0];
        destArray[destOffset + 1] = tmp[1];
        destOffset = destOffset +2;
    }
    </code>
But this still doesn't produce anything close to was recorded.

Comment: Update 2:  If I change my input source (getUserMedia) to use only 1 channel, instead of interleaving 2 channels, I can reproduce the sound.

Comment: Consider _editing_ the question with the updates instead of posting them as comments. It makes for a more coherent and useful question for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

It's too late, but still useful - I've posted a conversion code from `float[] samples` array to `byte[]` array there https://stackoverflow.com/a/42151979/4778700

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your indexing isn't quite right in the second loop.  You're looping over the `float` samples, and using the same index in the `short` output:

```
for (int x = 0; x < fArray.Length; x += 2)
```

Another thing (let's assume that the floating-point input is true IEEE 32-bit float samples in the range [-1.0,1.0], so we won't worry about converting).  Is it stereo input?  If so, then you'll need to combine the samples before converting to 'short'.  That's easy to do.  Just average successive pairs of `float` values (left channel/right channel).

The size of the output array should be correct.  Technically, it'd be something like this:

```
int inchannels = 2;  // doesn't have to be a variable, but shows 'stereo' input.
int numsamples = fArray.Length / inchannels;
byte [] bSamples = new byte [numsamples * sizeof(Int16)];
```

Then you should be able to do the conversion as follows.  Note that this assumes a stereo input, so it averages the float samples.

```
int outindex = 0;
for( int inindex = 0; inindex < fArray.Length; inindex += 2 )
{
    // 'insample' is the average of left and right channels.  This isn't
    // entirely accurate - if one channel is 0.0, then we should just use
    // the other channel verbatim.  But this is close enough.
    float insample = (fArray[inindex] + fArray[inindex+1]) / 2.0f;

    // The output sample.  It's probably better to use Int16.MaxValue
    // than the hard-coded value.
    Int16 outsample = (Int16)(insample * (float)Int16.MaxValue);

    // I'm old-school, so I'm a fan of 'unsafe'.  But you can use the
    // BitConverter that you were already using.  Actually, I would've
    // probably done this entire conversion in 'unsafe' mode.
    unsafe
    {
        fixed( byte * pbyte = &bSamples[outindex] )
        {
            Int16 * p = (Int16 *)pbyte;
            *p = outsample;
            outindex += sizeof(Int16);
        }
    }
}
```